# Qspatialite not loading in QGIS 2.6.1 for Mac

Tags: qgis, qspatialite

I am running QGIS 2.6.1 on MacOS (Mavricks). I have reinstalled the Qspatialite plugin, and am still encountering the same issue. The plugin will not open. Has anyone seen/over come this issue?

Comment: Do you are getting some error message? Could you check out the log messages too?

Comment: Its odd, there is no error message, and I do not see anything in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the newest update for this plugin has resolved the issue.